# Read XML in spark

Tags: xml, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-xml

I am trying to read xml/nested xml in pyspark using spark-xml jar.

```
df = sqlContext.read \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")\
   .option("rowTag", "hierachy")\
   .load("test.xml"
```

when I execute, data frame is not creating properly.

```
    +--------------------+
    |                 att|
    +--------------------+
    |[[1,Data,[Wrapped...|
    +--------------------+
```

xml format I have is mentioned below :

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`heirarchy` should be *rootTag* and `att` should be *rowTag* as

```
df = spark.read \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml") \
    .option("rootTag", "hierarchy") \
    .option("rowTag", "att") \
    .load("test.xml")
```

and you should get

```
+-----+------+----------------------------+
|Order|attval|children                    |
+-----+------+----------------------------+
|1    |Data  |[[[1, Studyval], [2, Site]]]|
|2    |Info  |[[[1, age], [2, gender]]]   |
+-----+------+----------------------------+
```

and `schema`

```
root
 |-- Order: long (nullable = true)
 |-- attval: string (nullable = true)
 |-- children: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- att: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Order: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- attval: string (nullable = true)
```

find more information on [databricks xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml)

Comment: i tried executing but i am getting 'children' column in wrappedarray [WrappedArray([1,...|

Comment: can you share the schema you are getting ?

Comment: StructType(List(StructField(Order,LongType,true),StructField(attval,StringType,true),StructField(children,StructType(List(StructField(att,ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(Order,LongType,true),StructField(attval,StringType,true))),true),true))),true)))

Comment: AFAIK this just won't work. `rowTag` cannot be repeated deeper in the hierarchy.

Comment: @user9613318 I tested it with the exact data that the OP had posted. After successful testing only I answered it :) try it if you think it won't work

Comment: The exact data is way to small to correctly test parser behavior. Especially in `local` mode. Spark XML will seek file for the first occurrence of the row tag since split offset and start parsing from this point. So no, it is not deterministic behavior (same as testing on few records in local mode is not a proof of correctness in general).

Comment: I never thought so deeply . the user has asked a new question any way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433468/how-to-convert-multiple-row-tag-xml-files-to-dataframe

Comment: It is better to. Spark is a leaking abstraction, and "seems to work" is just not good enough, especially if things can fail silently.

Answer (score 3):

Databricks has released new version to read xml to Spark DataFrame

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-xml_2.12</artifactId>
     <version>0.6.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Input XML file I used on this example is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/sparkbyexamples/spark-examples/blob/master/spark-sql-examples/src/main/resources/persons.xml) repository.

```
val df = spark.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
      .option("rowTag", "person")
      .xml("persons.xml")
```

Schema

```
root
 |-- _id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- dob_month: long (nullable = true)
 |-- dob_year: long (nullable = true)
 |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- middlename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- salary: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _VALUE: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _currency: string (nullable = true)
```

Outputs:

```
+---+---------+--------+---------+------+--------+----------+---------------+
|_id|dob_month|dob_year|firstname|gender|lastname|middlename|         salary|
+---+---------+--------+---------+------+--------+----------+---------------+
|  1|        1|    1980|    James|     M|   Smith|      null|  [10000, Euro]|
|  2|        6|    1990|  Michael|     M|    null|      Rose|[10000, Dollor]|
+---+---------+--------+---------+------+--------+----------+---------------+
```

Note that Spark XML API has some limitations and discussed here [Spark-XML API Limitations](https://sparkbyexamples.com/processing-xml-files-in-spark/#xml-limitations)

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 3):

You can use Databricks jar to parse the xml to a dataframe. You can use maven or sbt to compile the dependency or you can directly use the jar with spark submit.

```
pyspark --jars /home/sandipan/Downloads/spark_jars/spark-xml_2.11-0.6.0.jar

df = spark.read \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml") \
    .option("rootTag", "SmsRecords") \
    .option("rowTag", "sms") \
    .load("/home/sandipan/Downloads/mySMS/Sms/backupinfo.xml")

Schema>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- body: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: long (nullable = true)
 |-- type: long (nullable = true)

>>> df.select("address").distinct().count()
530
```

Follow this 
http://www.thehadoopguy.com/2019/09/how-to-parse-xml-data-to-saprk-dataframe.html

Comment: Useful if you wanna use it in Pyspark instead of Scala.