# how to convert multiple row tag xml files to dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-xml

I have xml file having multiple rowstags. i need to convert this xml to proper dataframe. i have used spark-xml which is only handling single row tag.

xml data is below

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<generic
    xmlns="http://xactware.com/generic.xsd" majorVersion="28" minorVersion="300" transactionId="0000">
    <HEADER compName="ABGROUP" dateCreated="2018-03-09T09:38:51"/>
    <COVERSHEET>
        <ESTIMATE_INFO estimateName="2016-09-28-133907" priceList="YHTRDF" laborEff="Restoration/Service/Remodel" claimNumber="Hdchtdhtdh" policyNumber="Utfhtdhtd" typeOfLoss="Collapse" causeOfLoss="Collapse" roofDamage="0" deprMat="1" deprNonMat="1" deprRemoval="1" deprOandP="1" deprTaxes="1" estimateType="Mixed"/>
        <ADDRESSES>
            <ADDRESS type="Property" street="Pkwy" city="Lehi" state="UT" zip="0000" primary="1"/>
        </ADDRESSES>
        <CONTACTS>
            <CONTACT type="ClaimRep" name="Vytvyfv"/>
            <CONTACT type="Estimator" name="Vytvyfv"/>
        </CONTACTS>
        <DATES loss="2016-09-28T19:38:23Z" inspected="2016-09-28T19:39:27Z" completed="2018-03-09T09:38:49Z" received="2016-09-28T19:39:24Z" entered="2016-09-28T19:39:07Z" contacted="2016-09-28T19:39:26Z"/>
    </COVERSHEET>
    <COVERAGES>
        <COVERAGE coverageName="Dwelling" coverageType="0" id="1"/>
        <COVERAGE coverageName="Other Structures" coverageType="1" id="2"/>
        <COVERAGE coverageName="Contents" coverageType="2" id="3"/>
    </COVERAGES>
    <LINE_ITEM_DETAIL>
        <COV_BREAKDOWN>
            <COV_AMOUNTS desc="Dwelling"/>
            <COV_AMOUNTS desc="Other Structures"/>
            <COV_AMOUNTS desc="Contents"/>
        </COV_BREAKDOWN>
    </LINE_ITEM_DETAIL>
    <RECAP_BY_ROOM>
        <RECAP_GROUP desc="2016-09-28-133907"/>
    </RECAP_BY_ROOM>
</generic>
```

Comment: how do you want your dataframe to be ? can you provide the sample?

Comment: Not sure how it suppose to be..tried spark-xml to figure it out. but it is handling only single row tags....i want it to be in proper dataframe without any data lose.

Comment: did you go through the link i provided you in my previous answer ?

Comment: yes i did, i found parsing options in it but didint find way to handle multiple row tags.

Comment: isn't it supposed to be in one row? let me answer with what I have tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would **suggest you to read it as one rowTag (*generic element*) and later explode according to your needs**

First of all, **attributes of the elements should not contain line delimiter** so

```
<generic
    xmlns="http://xactware.com/generic.xsd" majorVersion="28" minorVersion="300" transactionId="0000">
```

should be

```
<generic xmlns="http://xactware.com/generic.xsd" majorVersion="28" minorVersion="300" transactionId="0000">
```

Once above amendment is done, you can read it using databricks xml as

```
df = spark.read \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml") \
    .option("rowTag", "generic") \
    .option("valueTag", False) \
    .load("path to xml file")
```

which should give you

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+----------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------------------------+
|COVERAGES                                                          |COVERSHEET                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |HEADER                         |LINE_ITEM_DETAIL                                   |RECAP_BY_ROOM         |_majorVersion|_minorVersion|_transactionId|_xmlns                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+----------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------------------------+
|[[[Dwelling, 0, 1,], [Other Structures, 1, 2,], [Contents, 2, 3,]]]|[[[Lehi, 1, UT, Pkwy, Property, 0,]], [[[Vytvyfv, ClaimRep,], [Vytvyfv, Estimator,]]], [2018-03-09T09:38:49Z, 2016-09-28T19:39:26Z, 2016-09-28T19:39:07Z, 2016-09-28T19:39:27Z, 2016-09-28T19:38:23Z, 2016-09-28T19:39:24Z,], [Collapse, Hdchtdhtdh, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2016-09-28-133907, Mixed, Restoration/Service/Remodel, Utfhtdhtd, YHTRDF, 0, Collapse,]]|[ABGROUP, 2018-03-09T09:38:51,]|[[[[Dwelling,], [Other Structures,], [Contents,]]]]|[[2016-09-28-133907,]]|28           |300          |0             |http://xactware.com/generic.xsd|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+----------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------------------------+

root
 |-- COVERAGES: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- COVERAGE: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _coverageName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _coverageType: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- false: string (nullable = true)
 |-- COVERSHEET: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ADDRESSES: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ADDRESS: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _primary: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _state: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _street: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _zip: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- false: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- CONTACTS: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- CONTACT: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- _name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- _type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- false: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- DATES: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _completed: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _contacted: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _entered: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _inspected: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _loss: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _received: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- false: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ESTIMATE_INFO: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _causeOfLoss: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _claimNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _deprMat: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _deprNonMat: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _deprOandP: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _deprRemoval: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _deprTaxes: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _estimateName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _estimateType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _laborEff: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _policyNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _priceList: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _roofDamage: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _typeOfLoss: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- false: string (nullable = true)
 |-- HEADER: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _compName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _dateCreated: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- false: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LINE_ITEM_DETAIL: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- COV_BREAKDOWN: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COV_AMOUNTS: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- _desc: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- false: string (nullable = true)
 |-- RECAP_BY_ROOM: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- RECAP_GROUP: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _desc: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- false: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _majorVersion: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _minorVersion: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _transactionId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _xmlns: string (nullable = true)
```

Inspecting the above dataframe, you can simplify it by doing the following

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df.select(f.col('COVERAGES.COVERAGE'), f.col('COVERSHEET.ADDRESSES.ADDRESS.*'), f.col('COVERSHEET.CONTACTS.CONTACT'), f.col('COVERSHEET.DATES.*'), f.col('COVERSHEET.ESTIMATE_INFO.*'), f.col('HEADER.*'), f.col('LINE_ITEM_DETAIL.COV_BREAKDOWN.COV_AMOUNTS'), f.col('RECAP_BY_ROOM.RECAP_GROUP.*'), f.col('_majorVersion'), f.col('_minorVersion'), f.col('_transactionId'), f.col('_xmlns')).show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you *dataframe with schema* as below

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-----+--------+------+-------+--------+----+-----+---------------------------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+------------+------------+--------+-----------+----------+------------+----------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------------+-------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----+---------+-------------------+-----+-----------------------------------------------+-----------------+-----+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------------------------+
|COVERAGE                                                         |_city|_primary|_state|_street|_type   |_zip|false|CONTACT                                      |_completed          |_contacted          |_entered            |_inspected          |_loss               |_received           |false|_causeOfLoss|_claimNumber|_deprMat|_deprNonMat|_deprOandP|_deprRemoval|_deprTaxes|_estimateName    |_estimateType|_laborEff                  |_policyNumber|_priceList|_roofDamage|_typeOfLoss|false|_compName|_dateCreated       |false|COV_AMOUNTS                                    |_desc            |false|_majorVersion|_minorVersion|_transactionId|_xmlns                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-----+--------+------+-------+--------+----+-----+---------------------------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+------------+------------+--------+-----------+----------+------------+----------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------------+-------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----+---------+-------------------+-----+-----------------------------------------------+-----------------+-----+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------------------------+
|[[Dwelling, 0, 1,], [Other Structures, 1, 2,], [Contents, 2, 3,]]|Lehi |1       |UT    |Pkwy   |Property|0   |null |[[Vytvyfv, ClaimRep,], [Vytvyfv, Estimator,]]|2018-03-09T09:38:49Z|2016-09-28T19:39:26Z|2016-09-28T19:39:07Z|2016-09-28T19:39:27Z|2016-09-28T19:38:23Z|2016-09-28T19:39:24Z|null |Collapse    |Hdchtdhtdh  |1       |1          |1         |1           |1         |2016-09-28-133907|Mixed        |Restoration/Service/Remodel|Utfhtdhtd    |YHTRDF    |0          |Collapse   |null |ABGROUP  |2018-03-09T09:38:51|null |[[Dwelling,], [Other Structures,], [Contents,]]|2016-09-28-133907|null |28           |300          |0             |http://xactware.com/generic.xsd|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-----+--------+------+-------+--------+----+-----+---------------------------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+------------+------------+--------+-----------+----------+------------+----------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------------+-------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----+---------+-------------------+-----+-----------------------------------------------+-----------------+-----+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------------------------+

root
 |-- COVERAGE: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _coverageName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _coverageType: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- false: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _city: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _primary: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _state: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _street: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _zip: long (nullable = true)
 |-- false: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CONTACT: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- false: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _completed: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _contacted: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _entered: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _inspected: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _loss: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _received: string (nullable = true)
 |-- false: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _causeOfLoss: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _claimNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _deprMat: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _deprNonMat: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _deprOandP: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _deprRemoval: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _deprTaxes: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _estimateName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _estimateType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _laborEff: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _policyNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _priceList: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _roofDamage: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _typeOfLoss: string (nullable = true)
 |-- false: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _compName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _dateCreated: string (nullable = true)
 |-- false: string (nullable = true)
 |-- COV_AMOUNTS: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _desc: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- false: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _desc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- false: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _majorVersion: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _minorVersion: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _transactionId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _xmlns: string (nullable = true)
```

Now you can transform it into multiple rows depending to `COVERAGE` or `CONTACT` or `COV_AMOUNTS` columns as *they are the only columns that can be exploded to multiple rows*.

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: great ramesh, but i am not able to read it. it is throwing me, emty dataframe. i have removed line delimiter manually in xml file. have you used any process to remove?

Comment: I removed manually too. try part by part to track down the bug. I mean you can try the first part of reading only .

Comment: resolved the bug. two things, what valueTag will do? and why we are using 'df.select' followed by columns ? what exactly happening there?

Comment: i am copy pasting it `valueTag: The tag used for the value when there are attributes in the element having no child. Default is _VALUE.` so it was creating empty values so I put false for that. df.select columns is just flattening the struct columns . Array columns cannot be flatterned that easily so I left them otherwise all the struct columns are flattened