# azure data bricks: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.xml

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm trying to read xml file using azure databricks using below code:

```
df = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml').options(rowTag='book').load(' /FileStore/tables/sample.xml')
```

I installed spark-xml:0.1.1-s_2.10 package:

[image]

But I'm getting below error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o285.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.xml. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:733)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:214)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.databricks.spark.xml.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(DataSource.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(DataSource.scala:710)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:710)
    at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:710)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should download the latest version "spark-xml" from the maven repository.

**Steps to install third party libraries:**

**Step1:** Create Databricks Cluster.

**Step2:** Select the cluster created.

**Step3:** Select Libraries => Install New => Select Library Source = "Maven" => Coordinates => Search Packages => Select Maven Central => Search for the package required. **Example:** (com.databricks:spark-xml_2.12:0.9.0) => Install

[image]

To read xml file using azure databricks us below code:

```
df = spark.read .format("com.databricks.spark.xml") .option("rowTag", "book") .load(inputFile)
```

For more details, refer "[Read XML in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50429315/read-xml-in-spark)".