# Create new columns from XML field within PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Within my DataFrame object I have a column `Foos`, as an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <foos> <foo id="123" X="58" Y="M" /> <foos id="456" X="29" Y="M" /> <foos id="789" X="44" Y="F" /> </foos>
```

Each `<foo>` has a `foo id`, `X` and `Y` attribute that I want to create a column for each.

How can I parse the XML such that I can create new columns for each attribute? Does this require a UDF for each attribute, or is it possible to extract all three into separate columns in one function?

So far I receive an error with:

```
parsed = (lambda x: ET.fromstring(x).find('X').text)
udf = udf(parsed)
parsed_df = df.withColumn("X Column", udf("Foos"))
```

Comment: Your XML ET query is wrong. There is no direct child called 'X'. Check https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html for the correct usage.

Comment: a detailed read here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50429315/read-xml-in-spark

Answer (score 0):

As **mck** suggested the **xml** doesn't look a correct one , you can install a maven package - **`com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:0.10.0`** and direcrly read a xml file using **`spark.read`**

```
df = spark.read \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml") \
    .option("rowTag", "foos") \
    .load("/FileStore/tables/test.xml")
df.show(truncate=False)
```

#### and this is what I am getting as per your xml file provided , you might need to look into the xml file

```
+--------------+--------------------------------+
|foo           |foos                            |
+--------------+--------------------------------+
|[, 58, M, 123]|[[, 29, M, 456], [, 44, F, 789]]|
+--------------+--------------------------------+
```